# Inserting or updating related models in Laravel(Many to many relationships)

Tags: php, laravel

I have these tables

> products table, categories table and category_products table(which is an intermediate table between the former 2 tables).

Now, according to Laravel document(Eloquent Relationship), it says "to attach a role to a user by inserting a record in the intermediate table that joins the model, use the attach method" like this

```
$user = App\User::find(1);
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

in ny case, I did this in the

> ProductsController

in order to get the

> lastInsertId 
>   (which I don't know how to do in laravel), I did this

```
$product_id = $product->save()
```

then do this(to insert each category_id and product_id into the category_products table)

```
foreach ($this->request->category as $cat) 
{
    $product_id->categories()->attach($cat, ['product_id' => $product_id]);
}
```

meanwhile, in the

> Product model

class, I have this method called

> categories

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
}
```

because, according to laravel doc, it says ***Many-to-many relationships are defined by writing a method that returns the result of the belongsToMany method.*** and it gave this example

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```

But to my surprise, I got this error

> Call to a member function categories() on boolean
>
> App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductsController::store :152
>   app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ProductsController.php :152

This is the

> store() method

of the

> ProductsController

```
public function store()
    {
        $new = new Product;
        $this->request->validate([
            'name' => 'bail|required|unique:products|max:100',
            'description' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'discounted_price' => 'nullable|numeric',
            'display' => 'required',
            'stock' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        foreach ($this->request->category as $cat) 
        {
            $this->request->validate([
                $cat => 'numeric'
            ]);
        }

        $new->name = $this->request->name;
        $new->description = $this->request->description;
        $new->price = $this->request->price;
        $new->discounted_price = $this->request->discounted_price;
        $new->stock = $this->request->stock;
        $new->display = $this->request->display;

        $product_id = $new->save();

        foreach ($this->request->category as $cat) 
        {
            $product_id->categories()->attach($cat, ['product_id' => $product_id]);// This is the line 152
        }

        $success = $this->request->session()->flash('status', 'Product was successfully updated!');
        return redirect('admin/products')->with($success);
    }
```